# Positioning form input fields for all browsers

Tags: css, forms, browser, input, position

This is my third attempt to solve this issue-- with the help of those here in the stackoverflow community, I think I am much closer to resolving it. The input fields on the contact form I have created are lowered in Chrome and Safari (in relation to FF) and higher in IE. I have implemented many of the suggestion I have been given here, but still no luck in positioning them for all browsers. I was able to make some progress by using normalize.css

I have set up a test page: http://tinyurl.com/d3pxoe2

Here is my contact form:

```
 <div id="contactcontainer" class="contactform">


 <form method="post" name="validation" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

 <div class="containerleftside">

 <input type="text" class="shared" name="firstname" autofocus placeholder="Your first name" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" style="margin-left:142px; margin-top: 108px;"/>
 <input type="text" class="shared" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" style="margin-left:140px; margin-top:2px;"/>
 <input type="text" class="shared" name="email" placeholder="Your email name" value="<?php echo $email;?>" style="margin-left:84px; margin-top:1px;" />
 <input type="text" class="shared" name="location" placeholder="Your location" value="<?php echo $location;?>" style="margin-left: 116px; margin-top:0px;"/>

 </div><!--close of container left-->

 <div align="right" class="containerrightside">

 <textarea name="message" placeholder="What say you?"></textarea>
 <img style="margin-top:-10px; float:right; margin-right:3px;" src="CaptchaSecurityImages.php" />

 <p style="float:left; margin-top:-10px; text-align:left; font-family:'form', 'formIE';  font-size:24px; color:#000;">Security Code:</p>
 <input id="security_code" name="security_code" type="text" style="width:125px; float:left; margin-right:80px; height:1.4em; line-height:1.4em; font-size:1.4em; margin-top:-28px;"/>
 <input class="contact" type="submit" name="submitted" value="contactus" />

 </div><!-- end of containerrightside-->
 </div><!-- end of contactcontainer-->
 </form>
```

And here is the css:

```
 #contactcontainer {
background-image:url(../images/contactform.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:618px; 
height:318px; 
    margin:-10px auto;

 }

 .contactform{width:100%; height: 318px; margin:0 auto; padding:0;}
 .contactform input, textarea { background: none; font-size:1.4em; border:none; font-family:'form', 'formIE'; font-color:#999;}
 .contactform .contact{font-size:0px; width:91px; display:block; height:34px; float:right; margin-top:-25px;}
 .contactform .shared{height:1.4em; width: 150px; line-height:1.4em;}

 textarea {
height:120px;
color: #666;
width:260px;
margin-top:20px;

 }

 input:focus, textarea:focus {

 border:1px solid #99cc66;
 }

 .contact:hover {cursor:pointer;}

 .containerleftside {
width: 50%;
float: left;
margin-top:5px; 
text-align:left;
 }

 .containerrightside {
width: 48%;
float: right;
margin-top:110px;   
text-align:left;
height:208px;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be using [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) can help

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in
>   things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings,
>   and so on.

Comment: I have implemented normalize.css. Will it be useful to use both?

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the em values in the .contactform css to px values and see if it becomes consistent across ff, chrome, and safari. So long as those three are consistent, IE is very simple to fix.

Comment: Thanks Wolfram. I initially had them set to px and after no luck, changed to em